# Cuda Change single Value in Array

Tags: arrays, vector, cuda

I have a vector called `d_index` calculated in the CUDA device memory and I want to change just one value, like this...

```
d_index[columnsA-rowsA]=columnsA;
```

How can I do this without having to copy it to the system memory and then back to the device memory?

Comment: By starting a kernel with only one thread, passing the array and the value, and setting that value in the kernel code. Maybe you could elaborate where your problem lies, exactly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could either call kernel on `<<<1,1>>>` grid, that changes only the desired element:

```
__global__ void change_elem(int *arr, int idx, int val) {
    arr[idx] = val;
}
// ....
// Somewhere in CPU code
change_elem<<<1,1>>>(d_index, columnsA-rowsA, columnsA);
```

, or use something like:

```
int tmp = columnsA;
cudaMemcpy(&d_index[columnsA-rowsA], &tmp, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

If you only do this once, I think there is no big difference which version to use. If you call this code often, you better consider including this array modification into some other kernel to avoid invocation overhead.

Answer (score 3):

Host (CPU) code cannot directly access device memory, so you have two choices:

- Launch a single thread kernel (e.g. `update_array<<<1,1>>>(index, value)`)
- Use `cudaMemcpy()` to the location
- Use [thrust](http://code.google.com/p/thrust/) device_vector

Of course updating a single value in an array is very inefficient, hopefully you've considered whether this is necessary or perhaps it could be avoided? For example, could you update the array as part of the GPU code?

Answer (score 0):

I think since the d_index array is in the device memory, it can be directly accessed by every thread.